# XTR116 4-20 mA Transmitter Measuring Problem

Tags: current, amplifier

I have created the following circuit:

[image]

On the DAC side, output in the range of 0-4.095 V, VREF = 4.095 and VCC_ISO = 5 volts. Totally normal. But XTR116, I cannot control less than 16 mA current. Between 16-20 mA ıs normal. But I have never seen less than 16 mA. Vcompliance > +7.5. (So no problem.) I can not figure out. Anybody have an idea?

Original Circuit: https://medium.com/electronza/4-20ma-current-loop-arduino-tutorial-part-i-hardware-bb50935da42e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot draw unlimited current from the regulator in the XTR116 and still reach the lower limit of < 4mA. It's just a linear regulator, after all.

The XTR116 draws 0.3mA itself, so you have perhaps 3-3.5mA to play with. I suspect you are drawing much more than that.

Comment: I did not understand .I can not see less than 16mA on current loop. And XTR116 5V regulator for external circuit. And external component(MCP4921) works good.

Comment: What are those two chips that cross the isolation barrier, and what  total supply current do they draw from Vcc_iso?

Comment: Digital Isolation chips: HCPL2631. I guess , got it did you mean. Sorry I am embedded system developer . (software) . I am beginner on Power and amplifiers.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is all about VCC_ISO. I removed DAC side. 
I gave the voltage manually VIN. It is perfect . Thank you so much

Comment: So, VCC_ISO (XTR116-Vreg) is good enough to power the MCP4921, but HCPL2631's cause it to draw more current and so the system output doesn't go below 16mA. Am I getting it right? @SpehroPefhany

Comment: You must draw less than about 3mA total from the regulator or it won't be able to get down to 4mA when required.